# Lockscreen lag Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

Problem occurs while clicking any key trying to go into the screen to type the password and unlock the screen. Time lag between the click and apperance of the password edit box is around 20 seconds. Is there any setting to shorten this time or its a bug?

Ubuntu details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

1. System information:

```
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Latitude 5591
Version: Not Specified
Serial Number: 719GZW2
UUID: 4c4c4544-0031-3910-8047-b7c04f5a5732
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: 0819
Family: Latitude
```

2. The amount of RAM installed and swap configured (`free -m`)
   [image]

Hard drive info:

```
Device Model:     SAMSUNG SSD PM871b M.2 2280 512GB
Serial Number:    S3TZNA0M402884
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 d00b797b8
Firmware Version: MVT23D0Q
User Capacity:    512 110 190 592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Apr  4 14:09:24 2022 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Moving from this screen:

[image]

To this screen:

[image]

Takes approximately 20 seconds

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the model of Dell you’re using (2) the amount of RAM installed and swap configured (you can find this with `free -m`) (3) what applications may be running while the desktop is locked. I’ve seen this in instances where a machine was “too busy” with other tasks to respond to the front end, but not with a mostly-idle system 

Comment: Hello. the pictures are not necessary and do not add anything to the question.  Sounds like the drive is winding up.

Comment: @matigo I added suggested info

Comment: @David What do you mean? Can you explain it little bit more?

Comment: Nothing more to explain the hard drive needs to start spinning unless SSD. That can take the most of the 20 seconds. You never said it was an SSD.

Comment: @David It is SSD drive, I just checked it

Comment: Then edit the question and add this. It is one of most common reasons for a bit slower system. With out proper and complete info hard to offer good advice.

Comment: I've added the additional information about the hard drive

Comment: Check your logs for what occurred during those 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user535733 suggestion I used Logs program and I analysed the logs during the unlocking stage. I found that the fingerprint management deamon failed to activate the service. There was a timeout set to 25000 ms which was the lag problem. The error log was:

```
[system] Failed to activate service 'net.reactivated.Fprint': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

After removing `fprintd` from the machine using `sudo apt remove fprintd` problem is fixed.

Thanks for the all hints that guided me to the solution.

Comment: I think this fixed it for me as well! The fingerprint scanner on this Dell laptop never worked well anyways.